# WebRTC video working on mobile browsers

Tags: mobile, webrtc, mobile-browser, progressive-web-apps, videochat

I am looking to build a progressive web application that utilises WebRTC for video chat. My aim is to retain functionality across all devices (Smartphone, Tablet, Laptop, Desktop) without having to create a native/hybrid version of my app. But before I start I wanted to know if its even possible to implement WebRTC on a mobile browser (like chrome on android phones or safari on iPhones/iPads). If it is possible are there any good examples?

Comment: Currently no Browser is supporting WebRTC on iPhone/iPad.  Apple is actively working on webkit to support WebRTC, we need to wait for some time or build a native app.

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC is officially supported by Safari 11 from jun 2017, i'm not sure about mobile.